# Learning how to use Snapcraft

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I have started a project to create handy network sensor that can be deployed in locations where physical security may be lax/ non-existent. The goal is to design a device that uses Ubuntu Core for (disk encryption and general device hardening) as its base OS and install zeek on top using Snap packages to capture network traffic.

I understand that you can set up and install apt repositories using snap eg.

```yaml
package-repositories: 
  - type: apt 
    key-id: AAF3EB044C49C402A9E7B9AE69D1B2AAEE3D166A
    key-server: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/zeek/xUbuntu_22.04/
    url: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/zeek/xUbuntu_22.04/
```

However I am missing how I install the Zeek package and run it as part of the 'parts'.

Does anyone know of any additional resources on designing snapcraft.yaml and apt repositories?

I have been going through the following resources (although they are lacking some completed examples):
https://snapcraft.io/docs/package-repositories#heading--ppa-properties
https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapcraft-overview

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.